# Converting a GenBank-like multiline record into a new file format (fasta format)

Tags: awk, text

I have a file with the following architecture:

```
 source          1..3566367
                 /organism="Laccaria bicolor S238N-H82"
                 /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                 /strain="S238N-H82"
                 /db_xref="taxon:486041"
 gene            <143..>783
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_300552"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069681"
 mRNA            join(<143..224,274..309,357..470,524..>783)
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_300552"
                 /product="helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC
                 type"
                 /note="Has EST support"
                 /transcript_id="XM_001873113.1"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069681"
 CDS             join(143..224,274..309,357..470,524..783)
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_300552"
                 /note="Helix-turn-helix transcription factor; AraC type"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /product="helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC
                 type"
                 /protein_id="XP_001873148.1"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069681"
                 /translation="MHAKIFLTILFASAVSVYASPQLEERQILSGVVSAITSAGGAVA
                 SGVTSVAGQVTSVAGSIGGDITSEAGQVFQTVTSIGGKAVTIVTSVGGDAITLATSGA
                 GVATSKFGSVYTVATAAAASEASAATGKSSAALPIHGLQSSLIVGLVTVVGSALLGAA
                 ITL"
 gap             1104..3435
                 /estimated_length=2332
 gene            complement(<3738..>4636)
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_242762"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069481"
 mRNA            complement(join(<3738..3852,3910..4045,4101..4244,
                 4296..4356,4409..4491,4540..4565,4620..>4636))
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_242762"
                 /product="predicted protein"
                 /transcript_id="XM_001873722.1"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069481"
 CDS             complement(join(3738..3852,3910..4045,4101..4244,
                 4296..4356,4409..4491,4540..4565,4620..>4636))
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_242762"
                 /note="Ribulose-5-phosphate 3-epimerase. RPE2. Fourth step
                 of pentose phosphate pathway; Ribulose-5-phosphate
                 3-epimerase. RPE2. TRuncated gene. No EST evidence"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="XP_001873757.1"
                 /db_xref="InterPro:IPR000056"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069481"
                 /translation="LDVMDGHFVPNITMGAPILSCVHKGVPGIFMDCHMMVAKPEQWV
                 DDIADAGGSLYCFHIEATSDPVSLINTIHKRNMKAGVAISPDTPSTAITDEIANAADM
                 LLVMTVYPGRGGQKFIERCVPKVAELRARFPEKDIEVDGGVGPNTIGICADAGCNVIV
                 AGTAIFGSENPMEVIQRLKDTVNAAQAQSGAKY"
 gap             4637..5256
                 /estimated_length=620
 gap             7701..7750
                 /estimated_length=50
```

Within this file, the records I am interested are the ones that start with the word `CDS`:

```
 CDS             join(143..224,274..309,357..470,524..783)
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_300552"
                 /note="Helix-turn-helix transcription factor; AraC type"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /product="helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC
                 type"
                 /protein_id="XP_001873148.1"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069681"
                 /translation="MHAKIFLTILFASAVSVYASPQLEERQILSGVVSAITSAGGAVA
                 SGVTSVAGQVTSVAGSIGGDITSEAGQVFQTVTSIGGKAVTIVTSVGGDAITLATSGA
                 GVATSKFGSVYTVATAAAASEASAATGKSSAALPIHGLQSSLIVGLVTVVGSALLGAA
                 ITL"
 CDS             complement(join(3738..3852,3910..4045,4101..4244,
                 4296..4356,4409..4491,4540..4565,4620..>4636))
                 /locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_242762"
                 /note="Ribulose-5-phosphate 3-epimerase. RPE2. Fourth step
                 of pentose phosphate pathway; Ribulose-5-phosphate
                 3-epimerase. RPE2. TRuncated gene. No EST evidence"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="XP_001873757.1"
                 /db_xref="InterPro:IPR000056"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:6069481"
                 /translation="LDVMDGHFVPNITMGAPILSCVHKGVPGIFMDCHMMVAKPEQWV
                 DDIADAGGSLYCFHIEATSDPVSLINTIHKRNMKAGVAISPDTPSTAITDEIANAADM
                 LLVMTVYPGRGGQKFIERCVPKVAELRARFPEKDIEVDGGVGPNTIGICADAGCNVIV
                 AGTAIFGSENPMEVIQRLKDTVNAAQAQSGAKY"
```

From them, I would like to convert the information on these records into the following format:

```
>XP_001873148.1 GeneID:6069681 LACBIDRAFT_300552 helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC
MHAKIFLTILFASAVSVYASPQLEERQILSGVVSAITSAGGAVA
SGVTSVAGQVTSVAGSIGGDITSEAGQVFQTVTSIGGKAVTIVT
SVGGDAITLATSGAGVATSKFGSVYTVATAAAASEASAATGKSS
AALPIHGLQSSLIVGLVTVVGSALLGAAITL
>XP_001873757.1 GeneID:6069481 LACBIDRAFT_242762 hypothetical protein
LDVMDGHFVPNITMGAPILSCVHKGVPGIFMDCHMMVAKPEQWV
DDIADAGGSLYCFHIEATSDPVSLINTIHKRNMKAGVAISPDTP
STAITDEIANAADMLLVMTVYPGRGGQKFIERCVPKVAELRARF
PEKDIEVDGGVGPNTIGICADAGCNVIVAGTAIFGSENPMEVIQ
RLKDTVNAAQAQSGAKY
```

The records of this new file should start with the ">" symbol and contain the following information extracted from:

`XP_001873148.1` From:  `/protein_id="XP_001873148.1"`

`GeneID:6069681` From:  `/db_xref="GeneID:6069681"`

`LACBIDRAFT_300552` From: `/locus_tag="LACBIDRAFT_300552"`

`helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC` From: `/product="helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC`

Finally, the sequence:

```
MHAKIFLTILFASAVSVYASPQLEERQILSGVVSAITSAGGAVA
SGVTSVAGQVTSVAGSIGGDITSEAGQVFQTVTSIGGKAVTIVT
SVGGDAITLATSGAGVATSKFGSVYTVATAAAASEASAATGKSS
AALPIHGLQSSLIVGLVTVVGSALLGAAITL
```

Can we 'folded' to any number (usually 80, 44 in this example)

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction to get this done using AWK, not Perl or Python. The Python/Perl tools I used to perform this task are increasingly becoming harder to maintain/compile. I hope/believe that good/old AWK has the potential to perform these tasks.

Comment: Is there any reason, other than human readability, for folding and unfolding the lines? In general, unfolded lines are better if only programs parse these files.

Comment: Excellent question. In the field of Bioinformatics there is this 'dogma' that you should be able to 'see' the sequence, because in the past sequences were displayed as part of publications. The requested format printed here is called 'Fasta' and although it does not reject single lines, is not defined that [https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp](way). So, 'No', the sequence could be displayed as a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your data I find it best to first build an array to contain that mapping (`f[]`) below and then you can just access the values by their tags/names.

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and then taking advantage of the `\s/\S` gawk extensions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    wid=(wid ? wid : 44)
}
/^ ?\S/ {
    prt()
    key = $1
    sub(/\s*\S+/,"")
}
{
    gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"")
    rec = (rec == "" ? "" : rec " ") $0
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   f, tag, val) {
    if ( key == "CDS" ) {
        while ( match(rec,/\/([^=]+)=(\S+|"[^"]+")/,a) ) {
            tag = a[1]
            val = a[2]
            gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
            f[tag] = val
            rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }

        gsub(/\s+/,"",f["translation"])
        gsub(".{"wid"}","&"RS,f["translation"])
        sub(RS"$","",f["translation"])

        print ">" f["protein_id"], f["db_xref"], f["locus_tag"], f["product"]
        print f["translation"]
    }
    rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>XP_001873148.1 GeneID:6069681 LACBIDRAFT_300552 helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC type
MHAKIFLTILFASAVSVYASPQLEERQILSGVVSAITSAGGAVA
SGVTSVAGQVTSVAGSIGGDITSEAGQVFQTVTSIGGKAVTIVT
SVGGDAITLATSGAGVATSKFGSVYTVATAAAASEASAATGKSS
AALPIHGLQSSLIVGLVTVVGSALLGAAITL
>XP_001873757.1 GeneID:6069481 LACBIDRAFT_242762 hypothetical protein
LDVMDGHFVPNITMGAPILSCVHKGVPGIFMDCHMMVAKPEQWV
DDIADAGGSLYCFHIEATSDPVSLINTIHKRNMKAGVAISPDTP
STAITDEIANAADMLLVMTVYPGRGGQKFIERCVPKVAELRARF
PEKDIEVDGGVGPNTIGICADAGCNVIVAGTAIFGSENPMEVIQ
RLKDTVNAAQAQSGAKY
```

If you want to use a different width for the `translation` field then you can either change the code or specify it on the command line:

```
$ awk -v wid=80 -f tst.awk file
>XP_001873148.1 GeneID:6069681 LACBIDRAFT_300552 helix-turn-helix transcription factor, AraC type
MHAKIFLTILFASAVSVYASPQLEERQILSGVVSAITSAGGAVASGVTSVAGQVTSVAGSIGGDITSEAGQVFQTVTSIG
GKAVTIVTSVGGDAITLATSGAGVATSKFGSVYTVATAAAASEASAATGKSSAALPIHGLQSSLIVGLVTVVGSALLGAA
ITL
>XP_001873757.1 GeneID:6069481 LACBIDRAFT_242762 hypothetical protein
LDVMDGHFVPNITMGAPILSCVHKGVPGIFMDCHMMVAKPEQWVDDIADAGGSLYCFHIEATSDPVSLINTIHKRNMKAG
VAISPDTPSTAITDEIANAADMLLVMTVYPGRGGQKFIERCVPKVAELRARFPEKDIEVDGGVGPNTIGICADAGCNVIV
AGTAIFGSENPMEVIQRLKDTVNAAQAQSGAKY
```

Comment: Ed, Using `GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0`, I am getting the `awk: tst.awk:1: (FILENAME=GBFFTest2 FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted` error. Suggestions?

Comment: The code doesn't do any division so you must've done something wrong when you copy/pasted it.

Comment: You are right. The problem was with the 'test' file that I had copy and pasted from this site. When I run the script with another test file, it executed as expected. Comparing the two files, the difference between them is that the one that did not work had extra spaces at the start of each line, whereas the one that did work only had one. So, my question is: How sensitive is this script and AWK in general to spaces at the start of the line? (BTW: I am running the script now on a genome file, is taking long, I hope it works...)

Comment: First, the code you generated works like a charm. Thanks!. Second, it does work well in real genome files, and it is fast. Third, it is VERY sensitive to spaces at the start of lines. While it tolerates one space at the start of the line, it does not work if there is more that one space or if you remove all apaces at the start of the lines. Also,  indentation between the line containing the "CDS" identifier and the other lines is important. Lines must be 'inside' the CDS ID, for this to work. By far this code will help us tremendously.

Comment: @RodolfoAramayo glad it's helping. Awk is a tool for manipulating text. The code you write in it is as "sensitive" to anything as you make it. You posted input that's in a specific format, that's all I have to go on, so I wrote a tool that'd work for input in that format. If your real input doesn't all conform to that format then YMMV with what the script might do with that as input. Having said that, it doesn't particularly care how many spaces you have at the start of a line **except** that it needs some way to distinguish a line that starts with a key value like `CDS` from other lines ...

Comment: In your sample input those `key` lines start with a single blank char followed by a non-spaces key while all other lines start with multiple blan s so that is what I wrote the script to use to identify such lines (`/^ ?\S/`). If that's not how to identify such lines in your real data then just change that condition to be whatever it should be. In particular, if you remove all spaces at the start of all lines then it's not obvious at all how you'll be able to identify lines that contain the key field vs any other line. Post a new question if your sample input in this one isn't adequate.

Comment: And to answer `How sensitive is ... AWK in general to spaces at the start of the line?` - awk is no more sensitive to spaces or anything else than C or any other tool. The code you write in it is as sensitive as you write it to be.

Comment: if you squint hard enough at the "key" lines and try to find a "distiguishing" factor, this particular change seems to work with multiple leading spaces and/or missing ones: change original `/^ ?\S/` to `NF==2 && !/"/` - of course YMMV.
I agree with @EdMorton about original data having more "distinguishing" criteria to be used.

Comment: @vgersh99 That would fail if a line that just said `foo bar` (assume `foo` and `bar` are both strings that are about half the max line width) appeared inside a quoted string that started on the line before it and ended on the line after.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm having hard time visualizing your statement, but I believe you. I've come up with the alternative based on the OPs sample data *and* added flexibility of the leading/lack of spaces for the `key` lines. It's definitely not a deterministic mod and the OP's MMV. Definitely a more reliable "distinguishing" factor should be employed that would require the OP changing the format of the data. Thanks!

Comment: @vgersh99 Imagine if `/note="Ribulose-5-phosphate 3-epimerase. RPE2. Fourth step<newline>
                 of pentose phosphate pathway; Ribulose-5-phosphate<newline>
                 3-epimerase. RPE2. TRuncated gene. No EST evidence"` in the current input was `/note="Ribulose-5-phosphate 3-epimerase. RPE2. Fourth step<newline>
                 fooooooooooooooooooooooooooo; barrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr<newline>
                 3-epimerase. RPE2. TRuncated gene. No EST evidence"` instead. That middle line would satisfy your condition of `NF==2 && !/"/` but not be what we want to hit.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's true and there might other cases as well dealing with all kinds of permutations...
For whatever it's worth, here're the mods for this case and the other covered previously - I hate post as an answer (as it's not really mine): `NF==2 && !p && !/"/ {
    prt()
    key = $1
    sub(/\s*\S+/,"")
}
{
    if (p)
       p=(sub(/"/,"&"))?0:p
    else
       p=(n=gsub(/"/,"&"))?n%2:0

    gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"")
    rec = (rec == "" ? "" : rec " ") $0
}
`

Comment: @vgersh99 If the OP posts a new question with sample input that's more accurately representative of their real data then we can see what they really have and design to suit.

Comment: The code above works well (so far) as tested on several files obtained from different organisms