# How can I Re-Format the fields of a fasta file header and fold the sequence?

Tags: awk, text

- One of the most used files in Bioinformatics is the [fasta file
  format](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp).
- Fasta files are simple: They contain a "Header" record that starts
  with a ">", followed by the "Sequence" record, which is everything after the
  header but before the next record separator (i.e., ">").

```
>ENSP00000488314.1 pep chromosome:GRCh38:X:143884071:143885255:1 gene:ENSG00000276380.2 transcript:ENST00000618570.1 gene_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene transcript_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene gene_symbol:UBE2NL description:ubiquitin conjugating enzyme E2 N like (gene/pseudogene) [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:31710]
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLA
EEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDD
PLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
> next record...
> another one...
```

- The header can be very simple (e.g., ">ENSP00000488314.1") or complex.
- Complex headers important but variable information.
- In the case of the example sequences above (coming from [ENSEMBL](https://www.ensembl.org/info/data/ftp/index.html)), the header record is compossed of:

```
Field 01: ENSP00000488314.1                         <=Protein ID
Field 02: pep                                       <=Peptide record
Field 03: chromosome:GRCh38:X:143884071:143885255:1 <=Chromosome and chromosomal coordinates
Field 04: gene:ENSG00000276380.2                    <=Gene ID
Field 05: transcript:ENST00000618570.1              <=Transcript ID
Field 06: gene_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene       <=Gene Biotype
Field 07: transcript_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene <=Transcript Biotype
Field 08: gene_symbol:UBE2NL                        <=Gene Symbol
Up to here the fields are all nicely separated by spaces, and then...Field 09 (Variable)
Field 09: description:ubiquitin conjugating enzyme E2 N like (gene/pseudogene)
Field 10: [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:31710]       <=Predictable
```

- Many times **long** headers are not well received by other Bioinformatic applications, and so it is required to shorten headers.
- It would be nice to do that in a smart way. Therefore, using AWK, and using the example sequences below, I would like to:

1. First: Control the printing of the header records as follows:

- Always retain the first field:

```
>ENSP00000488314.1
```

2. But then be able to ommit and/or include fields. Examples:

```
>ENSP00000488314.1 gene:ENSG00000276380.2 transcript:ENST00000618570.1
Field: 01          04                     05
>ENSP00000488314.1 pep chromosome:GRCh38:X:143884071:143885255:1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:31710]
Field: 01          02  03                                        10
```

- For simplicity, totally ignoring Field 09 would be totally acceptable, but being able to use Field 10 would be nice

3. Then be able to "Fold" the sequence to a user specified number. For Example the records having sequence folded every 60 characters:

```
>ENSP00000441696.1 pep chromosome:GRCh38:14:21868839:21869365:1 gene:ENSG00000211788.2 transcript:ENST00000390436.2 gene_biotype:TR_V_gene transcript_biotype:TR_V_gene gene_symbol:TRAV13-1 description:T cell receptor alpha variable 13-1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12108]
MTSIRAVFIFLWLQLDLVNGENVEQHPSTLSVQEGDSAVIKCTYSDSASNYFPWYKQELG
KGPQLIIDIRSNVGEKKDQRIAVTLNKTAKHFSLHITETQPEDSAVYFCAAS
>ENSP00000488314.1 pep chromosome:GRCh38:X:143884071:143885255:1 gene:ENSG00000276380.2 transcript:ENST00000618570.1 gene_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene transcript_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene gene_symbol:UBE2NL description:ubiquitin conjugating enzyme E2 N like (gene/pseudogene) [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:31710]
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLA
EEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDD
PLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
>ENSP00000437680.2 pep chromosome:GRCh38:22:42140203:42141924:-1 gene:ENSG00000205702.11 transcript:ENST00000435101.1 gene_biotype:polymorphic_pseudogene transcript_biotype:nonsense_mediated_decay gene_symbol:CYP2D7 description:cytochrome P450 family 2 subfamily D member 7 (gene/pseudogene) [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:2624]
DPAQPPRDLTEAFLAKKEKAKGSPESSFNDENLRIVSVSNRRSTT
```

- Could become (sequence folded every 120 characters):

```
>ENSP00000441696.1 gene:ENSG00000211788.2 transcript:ENST00000390436.2
MTSIRAVFIFLWLQLDLVNGENVEQHPSTLSVQEGDSAVIKCTYSDSASNYFPWYKQELGKGPQLIIDIRSNVGEKKDQRIAVTLNKTAKHFSLHITETQPEDSAVYFCAAS
>ENSP00000488314.1 gene:ENSG00000276380.2 transcript:ENST00000618570.1
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLAEEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDD
PLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
>ENSP00000437680.2 gene:ENSG00000205702.11 transcript:ENST00000435101.1
DPAQPPRDLTEAFLAKKEKAKGSPESSFNDENLRIVSVSNRRSTT
```

- So far, the best I was able to do is to call a script containing the following code:

```
awk -v w=60 -f script.awk fasta_file.fa
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk
## Script.awk

/^>/ {
    if (seq != "") print seq; print $1,$4,$5; seq = ""; next
}
    {
        seq = seq $1
        while (length(seq) > w) {
            print substr(seq, 1,w)
            seq = substr(seq, 1+w)
        }
    }
    END { if (seq != "") print seq }
```

- The problem with the code above is that the fields $1, $4, and $5 are **hard coded**.
- An elegant solution to a similar problem was proposed by
  [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652927/converting-a-genbank-like-multiline-record-into-a-new-file-format-fasta-format), but, it requires me to **understand** the \s/\S gawk extensions and AWK arrays, which is something I am struggling to do.
- Any ideas on how to do improve the code above using AWK (not Perl/Python) will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use a shebang to invoke the awk interpreter in a shell script, just call `awk 'script' "${@:--}"` instead as the shebang has no worthwhile benfit but robs you of the chance to separate the things shell does well from the things awk does well within your shell script. `\s` and `\S` just mean "any space character" and "any non-space character" respectively just like the POSIX character classes in bracket expressions `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`. awk arrays are just plain old associative arrays (map a string to a value), just like in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows not only how to do what you want with awk but how to structure a shell script properly to call awk after parsing arguments (which you can't do if you invoke awk with a shebang so - don't do that). It uses GNU awk for gensub() and the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts ":w:f:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        w)  wid=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        f)  flds=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        *)  printf 'bad argument "%s"\n' "$opt" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"

awk -v wid="$wid" -v flds="$flds" '
BEGIN {
    wid=(wid ? wid : 120)
    flds=(flds ? flds : "protein gene transcript")
    numTags = split(flds,tags)
}
sub(/^>/,"") {
    if (NR > 1) {
        prt()
    }
    match($0,/(description:.*\S)\s+\[([^]]+)/,a)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    f["description"] = a[1]
    f["predictable"] = a[2]
    f["protein"] = $1
    f["peptide"] = $2
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = gensub(/:.*/,"",1,$i)
        f[tag] = $i
    }
    next
}
{ f["sequence"] = f["sequence"] $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   tagNr, tag) {
    printf ">"
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", f[tag], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    print gensub(".{"wid"}","&"RS,"g",f["sequence"])
    delete f
}
' "${@:--}"
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh file
>ENSP00000441696.1 gene:ENSG00000211788.2 transcript:ENST00000390436.2
MTSIRAVFIFLWLQLDLVNGENVEQHPSTLSVQEGDSAVIKCTYSDSASNYFPWYKQELGKGPQLIIDIRSNVGEKKDQRIAVTLNKTAKHFSLHITETQPEDSAVYFCAAS
>ENSP00000488314.1 gene:ENSG00000276380.2 transcript:ENST00000618570.1
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLAEEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDD
PLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
>ENSP00000437680.2 gene:ENSG00000205702.11 transcript:ENST00000435101.1
DPAQPPRDLTEAFLAKKEKAKGSPESSFNDENLRIVSVSNRRSTT
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh -w 60 -f 'gene_symbol chromosome' file
>gene_symbol:TRAV13-1 chromosome:GRCh38:14:21868839:21869365:1
MTSIRAVFIFLWLQLDLVNGENVEQHPSTLSVQEGDSAVIKCTYSDSASNYFPWYKQELG
KGPQLIIDIRSNVGEKKDQRIAVTLNKTAKHFSLHITETQPEDSAVYFCAAS
>gene_symbol:UBE2NL chromosome:GRCh38:X:143884071:143885255:1
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLA
EEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDD
PLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
>gene_symbol:CYP2D7 chromosome:GRCh38:22:42140203:42141924:-1
DPAQPPRDLTEAFLAKKEKAKGSPESSFNDENLRIVSVSNRRSTT
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh -w 10000 -f 'description' file
>description:T cell receptor alpha variable 13-1
MTSIRAVFIFLWLQLDLVNGENVEQHPSTLSVQEGDSAVIKCTYSDSASNYFPWYKQELGKGPQLIIDIRSNVGEKKDQRIAVTLNKTAKHFSLHITETQPEDSAVYFCAAS
>description:ubiquitin conjugating enzyme E2 N like (gene/pseudogene)
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLAEEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDDPLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
>description:cytochrome P450 family 2 subfamily D member 7 (gene/pseudogene)
DPAQPPRDLTEAFLAKKEKAKGSPESSFNDENLRIVSVSNRRSTT
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh -w 10000 -f 'predictable' file
>Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12108
MTSIRAVFIFLWLQLDLVNGENVEQHPSTLSVQEGDSAVIKCTYSDSASNYFPWYKQELGKGPQLIIDIRSNVGEKKDQRIAVTLNKTAKHFSLHITETQPEDSAVYFCAAS
>Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:31710
MAELPHRIIKETQRLLAEPVPGIKAEPDESNARYFHVVIAGESKDSPFEGGTFKRELLLAEEYPMAAPKVRFMTKIYHPNVDKLERIS*DILKDKWSPALQIRTVLLSIQALLNAPNPDDPLANDVVEQWKTNEAQAIETARAWTRLYAMNSI
>Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:2624
DPAQPPRDLTEAFLAKKEKAKGSPESSFNDENLRIVSVSNRRSTT
```